# How can I verify that my SQL Server edition is Express?

Tags: sql-server, restore, database-size

I have a SQL Server (version 11.0.5058). I tried to restore a database from a bak file and I got an error saying:

> CREATE DATABASE or ALTER DATABASE failed because the resulting
>   cumulative database size would exceed your licensed limit of 10240 MB
>   per database.

I was told that I do not have an Express instance, and thus I do not have a database limit of 10GB. I was not able to find information to verify this. Although under Help->About the word Express does not occur. How can I verify the database limit information?

What can be the problem?
Is this something in my configurations I can change?

Comment: Can you please add the O/P of select serverproperty('Edition') for the instance where you want to restore ?

Comment: Help -> About gives you version information about Management Studio. Note that this info remains unchanged regardless of edition/version you're connected to, even if you're not connected to anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to check the `SERVERPROPERTY ('Edition') AS ServerEdition` to find if your installed instance is an Express edition or standard or enterprise.

You can use below T-SQL :

```
SELECT
   SERVERPROPERTY ('MachineName') AS PhysicalMachineName,
   SERVERPROPERTY ('ServerName') AS SQLServerName,
   SERVERPROPERTY ('Edition') AS ServerEdition,
   CAST(SUBSTRING(@@Version,charindex('SQL',@@version, 1),15) AS VARCHAR(255)) +  ' + ' 
       + CAST (SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel')AS VARCHAR (50)) + ' + (Build'
       + CAST (SERVERPROPERTY ('ProductVersion') AS VARCHAR (50)) +')' AS ProductVersion
```

Another variation that tells you the database size limit based on the version (note that -1 means unlimited)

```
SELECT
   SERVERPROPERTY ('MachineName') AS PhysicalMachineName,
   SERVERPROPERTY ('ServerName') AS SQLServerName,
   SERVERPROPERTY ('Edition') AS ServerEdition,
   CAST(SUBSTRING(@@Version,charindex('SQL',@@version, 1),15) AS VARCHAR(255)) +  ' + ' 
       + CAST (SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel')AS VARCHAR (50)) + ' + (Build '
       + CAST (SERVERPROPERTY ('ProductVersion') AS VARCHAR (50)) +')' AS ProductVersion
    , case  when cast(SERVERPROPERTY ('Edition') as varchar(255)) like '%express%'
                then 
                    case 
                        when (
                                CAST(PARSENAME(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') as varchar(128)), 4) as int) >=10  -- major
                             and CAST(PARSENAME(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') as varchar(128)), 3) as int) in (0,50) -- minor
                              ) then 10  -- this is sql server 2008R2 and up
                        when (
                                CAST(PARSENAME(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') as varchar(128)), 4) as int) <= 10
                             and CAST(PARSENAME(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') as varchar(128)), 3) as int) < 50
                              ) then 4  -- this is sql server 2008 and less
                      end
                        else -1
        end  as EditionLimit
```

Starting sql server 2008R2, [Express edition database limit was increased from 4GB to 10GB](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2010/04/21/sql-server-2008-r2-express-database-size-limit-increased-to-10gb/).

Comment: Well, that very clearly showed that I have an Express edition after all... Thanks, @Kin